# CSS: Trying to place image vertically centered inside of div...Chrome, Safari issues

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, safari, vertical-alignment

I recently added three new content areas on my client's homepage (http://aworldcurated.com/) and having some problems with the code and making it where the images appear centered vertically inside of each div,.

On Firefox, it's perfect. Seems to work great there, but on Chrome and Safari (Mac) the images are floating upward and appear cropped off. Very bad.

Here;s the code I'm using. Hopefully, one of you know of a fix.

HTML

```
<p><div class="home-img"><a href="/products/vegan-leather-carryall" title="Vegan Leather Carryall"><img border="0px" alt="Vegan Leather Carryall" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0471/0045/products/IMG_9478-Edit_medium.jpg?v=1451491340" /></a></div></p><h4 class="title" style="padding: 10px 0 0 0;">Vegan Leather Carryall</h4><span class="price">$ 90.00</span><p style="margin-top: 20px;"><a href="/products/vegan-leather-carryall" class="btn">Buy Now</a></p>
```

CSS

```
.home-img img {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will cover your needs:

You may use `display:inline-block` for the `img`s, to let them accept `vertical-align` property and set it to `middle`;

```
.home-img img{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```